# Cassandra query with data amount filter through average

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a database query problem in cassandra
I will explain what is my question with the simplest case I have a table with timestamps, value like (I will simplify timestamps)

```
00:01 - 7
00:02 -5
00:03 -5
00:04 -7
00:05 - 1
00:06 - 10
00:07 - 578
00:08 - 7
00:09 - 4
00:10 - 9
```

I want to have a query that will reply:

- 00:01-->average of the first 5
- 00:05 and the average of the next 10.
- ....

Shoul make that query by cql or is need to be made programming? The results will be millions and I want to adjust the granularity (the 5 number here for adjust the output)

Answer (score 0):

CQL does not yet have the ability to do calculations like this, but will have some limited ability to do this within a partition in C* 3.0. Depending on how big and how many partitions take place in the queries I would recommend a distributed analytics based solution like Spark or Hadoop.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4914

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you think that should be efficient to have another table with groups already made?